# Less AND greater than symbol

Tags: symbols

I need to know, if it's possible, how I can write a unique "less AND greater than" symbol in LaTeX: for example `X >< 5`.

Comment: Isn't it `<>` instead of `><`?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I'll write on tex.stack the next time... However, I was wrong to write: I wanted to say <>...

Comment: Do you mean `\times`?

Comment: Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: I'd use `\neq`. Mathematically it has the same meaning if I say `x =\= 5`.

Answer (score 15):

That's not possible (unless you write the greater than symbol followed by the less than symbol).

You can find a **comprehensive list of LaTeX symbols** [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

**EDIT:**

For something that looks like an horizontal X, check out `\times` and `\openJoin` in the document.

For one over the other, check `\lessgtr`, from comments I think that's what you're looking for : [image]

Comment: mmm are you sure? Because I red something like that in some books in the past... However thanks a lot for the link... It's wonderful!

Comment: I found one that looks like a `>` on top of a `<` but that's all... You don't like how `><` looks like? Are you looking for something more like an horizontal  `X`?

Comment: No no... I'm looking for something like a > on top of a <... sorry, but I think that I explained that very bad... How can I do that?

Comment: @Daniele Check my edit, is that it?

Comment: Perfect @alestanis, that's \lessgrt! Thanks a lot! But it doesn't work: which packages I have to use? I have amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm...

Comment: @Daniele Great! You're welcome :)

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work: which packages I have to use? I have amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm...

Comment: It's in page 24 of the document, I think you need mathabx

Comment: @Daniele: try `\newsymbol\lessgtr 1337` after loading `amsmath` and `amsfonts`. `:)`

Comment: The needed package is `amssymb`

Comment: The link is broken